# How to insert values of s column to another column of the same name. Also, I need to insert other values for different fields in the target column

Tags: sql

Query to insert values of a column from one table to another table column with same name. Also hardcode remaining values in same query

Suppose we have two tables. I tried the following query ;

```sql
Insert into table A (date, ICN, script)
values ('date', '(select ICN from table B)', 'script name')
```

Comment: What is your question here? What about your attempt didn't work? What RDBMS are you "really using? MySQL and SQL Server are *completely* different products.

Answer (score 0):

Combining hard-coded values and a table B as a source

```
Insert into  A (date, ICN, script) 
select 'date', ICN , 'script name'
from B
where ..<specify criteria to get paticular rows from B>
```

Omit WHERE only if all the B rows are relevant.